# AMD Raid SMART Tests Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, raid, smart

I have an AMD SB with Raid 1 set up through that. I installed Ubuntu Server with no problems. However I know through windows one can set up SMART Tests with AMD's software. Is there a way to run SMART tests on a recurring schedule in Ubuntu and have it email failures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found that smartmontools works even with hardware raid.

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

Information

```
smartctl -i /dev/sda
```

Turn SMART On for sda

```
smartctl -s on /dev/sda
```

Get estimates

```
smartctl -c /dev/sda
```

Run a long test

```
smartctl -t long /dev/sda
```

Display test results

```
smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
```