# SMART SSD values from a RAID1 array

Tags: ssd, raid, smart

I have two SSDs (both Intel 320 Series SATA II 160GB) as a RAID 1 array on a Dell 1950 server. The drives are attached to an SAS controller.

At this [askubuntu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26646/amd-raid-smart-tests-ubuntu-server) the poster has had success seeing SMART values on a RAID 1 setup.

Trying some of the commands suggested at the link I am getting no SMART values and in fact, as it says, the device lacks SMART capability. It seems unlikely that a standard that has been around for many years is not supported on these Intel SSDs so the failure message may not be accurate. How do I get SMART values through this RAID 1 setup? It seems to make no difference whether I query device `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sda1`, or `/dev/sda2`.

```
ls /dev/sda*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2
```

Trying the "information" option:

```
>sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-31-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Dell
Product:              VIRTUAL DISK
Revision:             1028
User Capacity:        159,450,660,864 bytes [159 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Logical Unit id:      0x600508e000000000121afe0b0af54004
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Tue Dec  6 19:23:24 2016 EST
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.
```

Trying the "turn SMART on" option:

```
>sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sda1
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-31-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
unable to fetch IEC (SMART) mode page [badly formed scsi parameters]
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

The question is how can I get SMART values on RAID 1 with a SAS controller to SATA drives on Ubuntu 16.04?

Edit with additional information: The controller is the LSI Logic SAS 1068E-IR which is also identified in the BIOS as a SAS6IR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via this thread [about SMART through the LSI Logic SAS 1068E controller](http://smartmontools-support.narkive.com/scblHKIc/is-lsi-sas1068e-supported-by-smartmontools) is information that the following can work:

`smartctl -i /dev/sg0`

The actual digit can vary (sgX).

Answer (score 0):

Your physical disk is hiding behind a virtual disk. You can get at it using the -d option to smartctl. See the manpage, but for instance,

```
smartctl -a -d megaraid,0 /dev/sda
```

might work.